# Start activity in a try/catch bloc

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I just want to know how to launch an Activity in a try/catch bloc, i made this

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
            try {
                Intent monIntent = new Intent(this,dialog.class);
                startActivity(monIntent);
                SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
@Override
                public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
```

But i have errors:

```
constructor Intent(IncomingCallReceiver, Class<dialog>) is not defined
Method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type IncomingCallReceiver
```

I want to show an alertdialog when having a call.
How can i solve this problem?

Thank you very much.
Whole class:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
        try {

            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                    try {
                        call.answerCall(30);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            SIPCommunicator wtActivity = (SIPCommunicator) context;

            incomingCall = wtActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
            incomingCall.answerCall(30);
            incomingCall.startAudio();
            incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
            if(incomingCall.isMuted()) {
                incomingCall.toggleMute();
            }

            wtActivity.call = incomingCall;

            wtActivity.updateStatus(incomingCall);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (incomingCall != null) {
                incomingCall.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What errors do you have?  Why are you trying to start in a try/catch block?

Comment: Please state what specific errors you are seeing and perhaps we could help you.

Comment: @Robert @Mayra @Jonathan Engelsma: please see my edited first post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are facing is not the `try catch` block, it's the fact that you are starting activity in a listener implementation. Substitute

```
Intent monIntent = new Intent(this,dialog.class);
```

with

```
Intent monIntent = new Intent(<Name of this class>.this,dialog.class);
```

and

```
 startActivity(monIntent);
```

with

```
<Name of this class>.this.startActivity(monIntent);
```

By `<Name of this class>` I mean the head class where you are writing your code.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you are launching a new thread from within a try/catch block.  This is bad practice as the thread can fail should an exception be being thrown.

Instead, declare a variable before the value, and assign to it on the line preceding the catch statement.

Also assign to it if the exception is raised, but a different value.

Then launch the thread outside the try/catch block, based on the successful evaluation of the variable.

Use callbacks to trap failed threads, not exceptions.

```
int x = 0;

try
{
   /* Do some logic here */

   x = 1;        // we have success

}
catch(Exception e)
{
   x = -1;      // failure
}

if (x > 0) 
{
   Intent monIntent = new Intent(this,dialog.class);
                    startActivity(monIntent);

   ...
}
```

Comment: And how doing this if i want to start an activity ?

Comment: Without seeing all your code, I cannot be sure.  Paste the whole class.

Comment: What is the Type of dialog.class?

Comment: Are you missing a constructor?   Do you actually have a method created elsewhere called startActivity() ?

Comment: i added the whole class! dialog.class launches an alertdialog.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie I would like to state my view:-
Try putting some error messages to find out where the error is occurring. Also check the log file.

Example of try catch:-

```
try
{
    //some code

    //Toast message on success
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msgStatusUpdatedSuccefully, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch (TwitterException e)
{
    //Toast message on failure 
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msgStatusUpdateFailed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I would check if my imports are all fine for all the api's that I am using.

Also does your main public class looks like the following to resolve the undefined error:-

```
public class StatusActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{}
```